# Why is useState within useEffect not working in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I use `useEffect()` to get a Firestore snapshot and parallel I want to count a value:

```js
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState({ mona: 0, phil: 0 });
  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshop) => {
      setTasks(
        snapshop.docs.map((doc) => {
          if (doc.data().wer === "Mona") {
            console.log("Mona + 1"); // This get's executed as expected (e.g. 3 times)
            setCounter({ ...counter, mona: counter.mona + 1 });
          }
          if (doc.data().wer === "Phil") {
            console.log("Phil + 1"); // This get's executed as expected (e.g. 6 times)
            setCounter({ ...counter, phil: counter.phil + 1 });
          }
          return {
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
            timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
          };
        })
      );
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ counter }); //this get's executed only 2 times.
  }, [counter]);
```

When the `console.log()` within the `map()` get executed correct, why does the setCounter doesn't execute or update the counter correct?

The `console.log({ counter });` btw gives nothing more than:

```
{counter: {mona: 0, phil: 0}}
{counter: {mona: 0, phil: 1}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React sometimes batches updates to the state. Which means all your call to `setCounter` only trigger one effect.

Moreover the value of `counter` inside your function is also updated at the end of the function, therefore you are losing updates.

What you should do:

- First of all pass a callback to `setCounter` instead of using the value of `counter`. So change:

  ```
  setCounter({ mona: counter.mona, phil: counter.phil + 1 });
  ```

  to:

  ```
  setCounter(counter => ({ mona: counter.mona, phil: counter.phil + 1 }));
  ```
- To force useEffect to be called multiple times you have to opt-out of batched updates using `ReactDOM.flushSync`:

  ```
  import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

  // ...

  flushSync(() => setCounter(counter => ({ mona: counter.mona, phil: counter.phil + 1 })));
  ```

  In this way your `useEffect` should be called for every single change of the counter. Obviously this is less efficient than having the updates batched.

---

Since you are reloading the whole dataset everytime you want to re-count everything on each call to onSnapshot instead of simply modifying the current value.

In that case you can do this:

```
const newCounter = { mona: 0, phil: 0};
snapshop.docs.map((doc) => {
          if (doc.data().wer === "Mona") {
            console.log("Mona + 1"); // This get's executed as expected (e.g. 3 times)
            newCounter.mona += 1;
          }
          if (doc.data().wer === "Phil") {
            console.log("Phil + 1"); // This get's executed as expected (e.g. 6 times)
            newCounter.phil += 1;
          }
          // ...
});
setCounter(newCounter);
```

So you just compute the result and call `setCounter` once outside the loop with the final count. In this case you don't need to read the old state since you recompute it from scratch.

You *could* keep the old code and add a `setCounter({mona: 0, phil: 0})` outside the loop, but I believe it would be less efficient than computing the values outside react hooks and only calling the `setCounter` once.

Comment: This is working but when VSC reloads the browser automatically after save, the counter doubles the values and I have more counts than I have records in the database. Do I need to set the counter to zero on the beginning of the useEffect?

Comment: @JohnDoener I have added a possible solution for that problem. Yes you could add a `setCounter({mona:0, phil:o})` outside the loop, but, IMHO, if you are recomputing the whole state it's better to just do it without using the react hook and simply call `setCounter` once at the end with the final state recomputed

Answer (score 3):

The function you pass to `useEffect` closes over the `counter` variable.

When you call `setCounter` it updates `counter` in the store, and the hook re-renders. The effect hook **doesn't** run again because none of the dependencies (`[]` - there are none) have changed.

Next time the event handler set up by `onSnapshot` is triggered, it uses the **same** value of `counter` as the previous time. This means that `counter.phil` is still `0` inside the effect hook. You add `1` to `0` **again** and call `setCounter` but this value is the same as the previous value.

Since `counter` hasn't changed this time, the second effect hook which depends on the value of `counter` doesn't get triggered.

---

Pass a **function** to `setCounter` to get the most recent value instead of the original closed over value:

```
setCounter((latestCounter) => { ...latestCounter, phil: latestCounter.phil + 1 });
```